# What causes bedrock to randomly disappear in creative mode? (360 version)

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I started a massive platform of bedrock and I'm nearing the end but started noticing random chunks of bedrock are disappearing. I don't see any pattern but they are large chunks. I am building in the snow region of my map but I didn't think snow would dissolve bedrock after a time.

I also have a lava pit underneath the platform so maybe that will affect it as well? I was under the impression that bedrock was indestructible outside of creative mode but maybe things affect if in creative mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with PC Minecraft tells me this is either one of the following:

1. The chunks aren't being loaded properly or are taking a longer time to load. In this aspect, it will look like a cube (or column) of matter vanishes and you have the (temporary) ability to look into the surrounding blocks.
2. Lag in multiplayer, coupled with the before.
3. Very large maps (in the range of >1000 m from the first spawn).

Comment: It was probably a combo of all of these. Large map, multiplayer, and load time. They were all back when we started again this morning. Thanks.